# What tool works to adjust the Wahoo Aero pedals float?

Tags: pedals

Wahoo tells me that a Phillips #0 screwdriver will turn the float adjustments on their disc pedals. I have a genuine #0, and I cannot get good enough engagement to turn the float screws. All it wants to do is cam out. I suspect that this is actually a case of some more exotic cross-head (e.g. JIS). The alternative is that the adjustment bolt is just too tight to turn.

Has anyone out there succeeded in adjusting these, and if so, what tool did you use?

Comment: Start by cleaning out the screw head - it could have grit or dirt jammed in there to the point a tool doesn't get a good engagement.  Good luck!

Comment: This is about the two float adjustment worm screws of the Speedplay Zero cleats which need to be used with the Wahoo Aero Flat pedals, right? In my experience they are hard to turn but not extremely hard. Maybe try some silicone lubricant. Maybe a flat screw driver will actually get better grip?

Comment: Yes that's what they are, and these are brand new and so not dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [pictures in the manual](https://support.wahoofitness.com/hc/article_attachments/4409562739090/Wahoo_Speedplay_QSG_Rd27.pdf) you would use a phillips screwdriver.
Size 0 driver will probably fit.

[image]

zoomed in
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I read, and that's what I tried, and I can't get them to turn.

Comment: They are very hard to turn. Use a good screwdriver and plenty of force. Some penetrating lubricant can also help.

Comment: Oh, and if I remember correctly the cross of the screw head has the same depth all over and is quite deep, so It’s possible a flat screwdriver works better because it doesn’t tend to slip out.

Answer (score 0):

Given your pedals are used, there's an excellent chance the head has some grit in the recess, enough to hold the screwdriver out enough to limit engagement.

1. clean the area with a medium-stiff brush to knock off loose dirt
2. blast the area with penetrating oil, to loosen the thread.  Might take time to soak in
3. use a pick or sharp point to scratch out debris from inside the screw head
4. try and get the pedal supported so you're not pushing against yourself.  Put that crankarm forward so pressure down is against the drivetrain and not against empty air.  You may need an assistant.

Once the screw is moving, consider lubricating it better down inside the thread hole.  The underside of a pedal is a pretty harsh environment, so marine grease might be suitable.  Add this to your annual major overhaul or lube it as part of periodic bike maintenance.

Comment: Having trouble figuring out #4 applies to adjusting a cleat on a shoe. Are suggesting to clip the shoe into the pedal and then make the adjustment?